# Google doesn't show my site's results even for a direct search

Tags: google, google-search, seo

> In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 21 already displayed.
>
> If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.

When I do a direct search for my blog. This is very disturbing because I've created more than a dozen articles and none are shown in the SERPs for a direct search. The only way  to view my pages seems to be on the third page when all the results are exhausted there's the text I've paste above and it's linked. Now clicking that link is the only way to view my pages.

You can check this phenomenon out here:
http://google.com/search?q=moviesreva.blogspot.com/

Comment: The 'direct search' or site search, if I guess that's what you want to do, seems to be returning fine. https://www.google.com/search?q=site:moviesreva.blogspot.com You're searching for all occurrences of `moviesreva.blogspot.com` with your search rather than your actual site search.

Comment: Your search query is searching for the phrase `moviesreva.blogspot.com` - not searching within that domain (as Sathya suggests). But the indexed pages are all returning 404 - Not Found !?

Comment: On [google.com/search?q=moviesreva.blogspot.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=moviesreva.blogspot.com) I'm told that _Some potentially offensive results have been filtered out by Safe Search_. Maybe that's part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a new site. As per the SEO point, Your site should go into direct search only after the Google robots cache your blog information. It may took about 2 to 4 weeks(may be). It can cache only your contents not images. Once after caching your blog contents, there is a methodology called content duplication test will be taken place by Google robots.

If your contents are not unique (may be your one article matches with already exist article), the hold blog will be consider as duplication and will scroll to the 3rd, 4th, .. nth page during Google search.

No issues, You keep on posting your own articles, the frequent updation in your blog can give you good SEO & Alexa ranking in 3 to 6 months. But, it will take much time to make your site at the top of the Google search.

Answer (score 1):

Your site has 16 pages in Google's index which means it's been crawled and indexed and it's not being blocked or manually removed from the search results. Use a [site search](https://www.google.com/#q=site%3ahttp://moviesreva.blogspot.com/&start=0) to see this.

Searching on the URLs of your individual articles also shows them on page one, at least the few I tried. This also confirms they are in Google's index and also not being blocked or penalized.

But searching for your site using the names of your blog posts shows they are not always appearing on page 1 of Google. And your home page also is not appearing, as you mention.

I believe this is happening for two reasons:

**1. Home page - thin content**

This page is mostly images and a list of blog posts - all of which have movie names as their titles. So this page offers no unique content. Everything on this page can be found on other larger, older and more established site with higher authority and a lot more content.

**2. Blog posts - Thin / duplicate content**

These pages are titled using movie names, which means they are not unique and are competing with many other pages on similar websites. But the larger problem is the content on these pages is strikingly similar to content on other movie sites. It looks like a re-write of movie descriptions found on other well-known sites.

While this content is not an exact duplicate, it still might be considered duplicate content by Google because its meaning is essentially the same. It gives the same description that can be found on other sites.

Both thin and duplicate content can get your pages penalized. But they can also simply cause your pages to have very low visibility, so they appear several pages back from page one. That seems to be what is happening here.

Google explains this more in detail [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2604719?hl=en). They also offer suggestions on how to avoid thin and duplicate content situations.

I would suggest adding more content to your home pages that gives your opinion of these movies and that tells people what your site is all about. Then re-write your pages, again, from your point of view. Offer your visitors some insights or thoughts they can't get on any other website. Don't just describe the movies. Tell people what YOU think about them.